# C# boolean Value always returns false yet it is true in the database

Tags: c#, razor, model, boolean

I have the followin Code in Model class which has a data type
'bool'

```
public class MiscellaneousSettings
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Account_No { get; set; }
        public bool Percantage { get; set; }

        public decimal default_amount { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }        

    }
```

Then the code for controller where I get the data which I will display in view I am using dapper ORM to fetch and send the data to the database
and consume the sp

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                using (sqlConnection)
                {


                    var list_charge = sqlConnection.Query<MiscellaneousSettings>("get_miscellaneous_charges", 
                        new {  }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

                    return View(list_charge);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
```

Then the code for index View which shows 'No' for the boolean value while in the Database it shows the true value.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account_No)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.YesNo(item.Percantage)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.default_amount)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id=item.type}) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "#", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

I used the htm helper extenseion for decorating booolean 
values in the view to read Yes or No 
instead of checkboxes

```
 public static class HtmlHelperExtension
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString YesNo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool yesNo)
        {
            var text = yesNo ? "Yes" : "No";
            return new MvcHtmlString(text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this :  var text = (boolean)yesNo ? "Yes" : "No";

Comment: @AliMaleki `yesNo` is already declared as a `bool`

Comment: Your property is spelled `Percantage`. Is it `Percentage` in the database? It looks like you're using Dapper to execute the query. If the column names don't match, it wouldn't map them.

Comment: Thanks @madreflection such a mess spelling from me. Sorted it out. Big thanks.